# Maximum stack depth reached: 1

Tags: visualforce, standardsetcontroller

According to salesforce doc :

Total stack depth for any Apex invocation that recursively fires triggers due to insert, update, or delete statements  is 16.

But strangely for my case, I am getting the error in a visualforce page where i'm not doing any DML, only standardSetController initialisation :

Class code :

```
 public class VFC05_MassAssignOwner_EBSAP {
      public list<Opportunity> selection{get;set;}
      public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
      public VFC05_MassAssignOwner_EBSAP(ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl){
          opp = new Opportunity();
          selection = (list<Opportunity>) ctrl.getSelected();       
    }
}
```

In my page :

```
  <apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity"   
   extensions="VFC05_MassAssignOwner_EBSAP" recordsetvar="opp1" 
  tabstyle="Opportunity">
```

I'm getting the error at line :

```
 selection = (list<Opportunity>) ctrl.getSelected();`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work. In fact nothing to do with DML etc. It was related to duplicate variable usage. In my VF page my recordsetvar had the same name as a variable in my class :

Page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" 
           extensions="VFC05_MassAssignOwner_EBSAP" 
           recordsetvar="opp" 
           tabstyle="Opportunity">
```

Class:

```
public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
```